# Flutter Web submit form on enter key

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Is there a way to call the submit button when a user hits the enter button when filling out a form.  Here is my form code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String _email;
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Password Reset'),
      content: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Email',
                labelText: 'Email',
              ),
              autofocus: true,
              maxLength: 30,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Email is required';
                }
                return null;
              },
              onSaved: (input) => _email = input,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
              _formKey.currentState.save();
              var result = await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(_email);
              print(result);
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }
          },
          child: Text('Reset'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For a `TextFormField` the property to handle this would be `onFieldSubmitted`. You can copy the code from your `onPressed` of the `RaiseButton` to this. For e.g.

```dart
onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  _formKey.currentState.save();
//               var result = await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(_email);
//               print(result);
                  print(_email);
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                }
              },
```

A full example is available as a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/abhilas-csc/pen/GRoNNpG).

> You might be interested in `RawKeyboardListener` as well however it
>   doesn't recognize the `enter` key. But could listen to other keys such as `Shift`, `CapsLock` etc.

Comment: For a `TextField` (as opposed to a `TextFormField`), the property is `onSubmitted` which is a `void Function(String)`

Comment: How does RawKeyboardListener not recognize arguably one of the most important keys on the keyboard... Is that true?

Comment: @BrunoEly Yeah, it seems so. I guess it has something to do with `TextField` trying to handle it on its own

Comment: But what if I want to submit the form, not just the single field? I want to have a 'Save' button that should be triggered on 'Enter' key... Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Use either the [`onEditingComplete`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onEditingComplete.html) or [`onSubmitted`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onSubmitted.html) parameters of the `TextFormField` constructor, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the **TextFormField** has the `textInputAction` set to `TextInputAction.done` or `TextInputAction.go`